# Using a variable to change the name of an image displayed in an UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I'm a completely newbie to iOS and have been focussing on learning Swift. However I'm also dabbling in Objective-C.

I can't seem to find a way of changing the image displayed on my app dependent on a data value I have in a variable. I have text value "5" for example that i want to put between a text prefix and suffix so that I can use that as the file name to display in a UIImageView.
Ultimately I want to achieve "Prefix"+ variable + "suffix" into something I can pass to my image view. 
So far I have this.

```
 NSString *fileName = @"fhrs_";
fileName = [fileName stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@", self.ratingVal];
fileName = [fileName stringByAppendingFormat:@"_en-gb.jpg"];
```

when the code gets here "fileName holds the correct value for the file I want to display in the UIImageView.

```
vwImgRating.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"%@", fileName];
```

However I get a message when trying to compile that " Too many arguments to method call, expected 1, have 2.
Help!

Answer (score 0):

Replace the last line with this

```
vwImgRating.image = [UIImage imageNamed:fileName];
```

or

if you want to use format specifier than u can use

```
vwImgRating.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",fileName]];
```

Image needs a String and you are giving the String in the wrong format.